# Obtener extensión de un archivo codificado e Base64 Javascritp

Tags: javascript, c#, base64

tengo inicialmente un archivo en excel que estoy codificando en C# para pasarlo al front y desde ahí decodificar y descargarlo en el cliente, lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

`archivoBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String( File.ReadAllBytes(pathFile + nombreTabla + ".xlsx"));`

por lo que retornaría algo similar a esto
**UEsDBBQAAAgIAIFgfFRLJGJq9AAAAIAPAAAAeGwvsdcasdcd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sjZBNTsMwEIWvY...**

la idea es obtener el nombre y la extensión del archivo a partir de ese texto codificado, si decodifico sin especificar la extensión genera el archivo como un .txt por supuesto no me sirve

La forma en como lo decodifico es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo o si debo si o sí enviar la extensión de forma explicita

Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas directamente en el front [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob)? Por otro lado `Convert.ToBase64String(...)` convierte como tal el contenido del archivo a base64, no el nombre ni la extensión. Nota que lo que le pasas a  `Convert.ToBase64String`  como argumento es un archivo. ¿Cómo piensas entonces recuperar el nombre y la extensión de ahí? Mi recomendación, envíalo separado.

Comment: no se que metodo usas para convertir a base64 pero convirtiendo en el front con toDataUrl (son imagenes) el base64 me queda asi: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAgAElEQVR4Xux9B4Bc.....", fijate que viene la extension dentro del string

Comment: Hola @JaimeMenéndez quería verificar si era posible aunque no encontré forma, tienes toda la razón para este caso me toca enviarlo por separado, gracias por tu apunte

Comment: @HernánGarcia mi duda con el toDataUrl es que no se si funcione de la misma manera para almacenar archivos con distintas extensiones, por supuesto así sería mas sencillo obtener la info que quiero